# Error 99 connecting to localhost:6379. Cannot assign requested address. when running app connected to redis

Tags: python, redis

I'm building this python app inside a `docker` container, but cannot access the `Redis` port inside it.

Inside my `Dockerfile` I added the line:

```
EXPOSE 6379
```

but running the app raises the error `redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 99 connecting to localhost:6379. Cannot assign requested address.`

I have to mention that my app only pops items from the redis queue.

Edit:
My `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.9

ARG DATABASE
ARG SSL_TOKEN_PATH

ENV DATABASE=$DATABASE
ENV SSL_TOKEN_PATH=$SSL_TOKEN_PATH

COPY config/db_config.yaml db_config.yaml
COPY app/requirements.txt requirements.txt

ENV DB_CONFIG=config/db_config.yaml

COPY app/pydb/requirements.txt pydb/requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r pydb/requirements.txt

COPY app/ .

EXPOSE 6379

CMD ["python3", "-u", "process_file.py"]
```

Comment: How many images are you using? one for the python app and one for redis? Inside the python container you need to use the redis container dns, not localhost. As localhost inside a container points to the container itself, and redis should not be running there, but in a different one.

Comment: I'm using just one image - the python app image. So I should have two separate containers? One with redis and one with the python app?

Comment: The idea behing containers is that you use one container for each component of your application. That is one for your python app and another one for the redis server. From your question and comment it is not very clear what you are exactly doing. Could you provide please your complete `Dockerfile`

Comment: Since I want just to pop items from the redis queue, do I really need to have redis inside a separate container? To summarize, I have an app which processes a file popped from redis queue. I provided the whole `Dockerfile` in my edit.

Comment: Unless `process_file.py` is starting a redis instance, there is no redis server started or listening to connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to create a network in docker using the:

```
docker network create <name_of_network>
```

As `host` inside `redis` you must provide: `host.docker.internal`.

Finally run the container inside the created network using:

```
docker run --network <name_of_network> -d <image_name>
```

That solved the issue, and I didn't have to create new container just for `redis`.